# How do I refer to a picture I added in my essay?

Tags: citations, formatting

I'm trying to write an essay about the elements and principles of design in Michelangelo's *Pieta.* The essay must be in MLA format and I need to include a picture to visualize a central point I'm trying to make in one of my paragraphs.

> There is clearly a hierarchy here too, with the Virgin Mary at the
>   top, and Jesus at the bottom, and they seem to form the shape of a
>   triangle. (figure one or something)

How do I refer to a picture in this context, and furthermore, how I include pictures in an MLA formatted essay? Should there be any? This professor is pretty lenient about how it's formatted, so I'm just sticking with what most people know.

These are her instructions.

> 1. Cite all work using APA or MLA
> 2. Double space, font size 12, Times Roman font
> 3. A good paper will be 3 pages, not including photos (place your photos at the end)
> 4. No heading or title whatsoever! iLearn does that for you already

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good guide to MLA figures and tables may be found [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/14/).

In short, you simply say "Figure 1" for the first figure, "Figure 2" for the second, and so on.